# What Is default datatype of constant numbers in c?

Tags: c, types

```
float x=2, y=2.6;

if(x==2); 
if(x==2.0) //both these conditions evaluate to be true
```

But,

```
 if(y==2.6);
```

evaluates as false

Can anyone explain what's the default datatype of constant numbers and why am I getting such results

Comment: The default type is `double`

Comment: It is more complicated: `(y==2.6)` can evaluate in a number of ways.  Research   `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Comment: Use `double` for floating point numbers. Do not use `float` unless you know exactly why you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float constant `2.6` has the type `double`. To make the constant having the type `float` you should use the suffix `f` as `2.6f`. As the size of the type float is less than the size of the type double then values in an object of the type `float` are less accurate represented than in an object of the type `double`.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float x = 2.6f,  y = 2.6;

    printf( "x == 2.6f -> %d\n", x == 2.6f );
    printf( "y == 2.6 -> %d\n", y == 2.6 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x == 2.6f -> 1
y == 2.6 -> 0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
float x=2, y=2.6;
//           ^^^ double, internally converted to float during the initialization
//      ^ int, internally converted to float during the initialization

if (x == 2) // compare double converted from float (x) with double converted from int (2)
if (x == 2.0) // compare double converted from float (x) with double (2.0)

if (y == 2.6) // compare double converted from float (y) with double (2.6)
```

Note about the last condition: initially `2.6` (a double) was converted to float; converting that float back to double does not guarantee the same value.

```
(double)(float)2.6 != 2.6
```

---

It goes kinda like this:

```
                 2.6 is 0b10.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001
          (float)2.6 is 0b10.10011001100110011001100
  (double)(float)2.6 is 0b10.1001100110011001100110000000000000000000000000000000
          difference is                             ^ approx. ~0.000000095367
```

Comment: I was surprise by last condition myself. Although it is true, but I guess this can be really bug-prone (and hard to catch bugs too).